# How do I fix the code to scrape Zomato website?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I wrote this code but got this as the error "IndexError: list index out of range" after running the last line. Please, how do I fix this?

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
                                           like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}
    response = requests.get("https://www.zomato.com/bangalore/top-restaurants",headers=headers)

    content = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")

    top_rest = soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class": "sc-bblaLu dOXFUL"})
    list_tr = top_rest[0].find_all("div",attrs={"class": "sc-gTAwTn cKXlHE"})

list_rest =[]
for tr in list_tr:
    dataframe ={}
    dataframe["rest_name"] = (tr.find("div",attrs={"class": "res_title zblack bold nowrap"})).text.replace('\n', ' ')
    dataframe["rest_address"] = (tr.find("div",attrs={"class": "nowrap grey-text fontsize5 ttupper"})).text.replace('\n', ' ')
    dataframe["cuisine_type"] = (tr.find("div",attrs={"class":"nowrap grey-text"})).text.replace('\n', ' ')
    list_rest.append(dataframe)
list_rest
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because top_rest is empty when you attempt to get the first element of it **"top_rest[0]"**. The reason for that is because the first class your attempting to reference is dynamically named. You will notice if you refresh the page the same location of that div will not be named the same. So when you attempt to scrape you get empty results.

An alternative would be to scrape ALL divs, then narrow in on the elements you want, be mindful of the dynamic div naming schema so from one request to another you will get different results:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get("https://www.zomato.com/bangalore/top-restaurants",headers=headers)

content = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")

top_rest = soup.find_all("div")
list_tr = top_rest[0].find_all("div",attrs={"class": "bke1zw-1 eMsYsc"})
list_tr
```

Comment: I tried that and tried accessing the list elements i.e. one restaurant information one by one using a loop with this code in the edited code 'after the one you helped answer' up there. I'm sorry this may seem basic but I am new to webscraping and just decided to lay my hands on real life projects.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did a project that made me research scraping the Zomato's website in Manila, Philippines. I used Geolibrary to get the longitude and latitude values of Manila City, then scraped the restaurants' details using this information.
ADD: You can get your own API key on zomato website to make up to 1000 calls in a day.

```
# Use geopy library to get the latitude and longitude values of Manila City.
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

address = 'Manila City, Philippines'
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent = 'Makati_explorer')
location = geolocator.geocode(address)
latitude = location.lenter code hereatitude
longitude = location.longitude
print('The geographical coordinate of Makati City are {}, {}.'.format(latitude, longitude))

# Use Zomato's API to make call
headers = {'user-key': '617e6e315c6ec2ad5234e884957bfa4d'}
venues_information = []

for index, row in foursquare_venues.iterrows():
    print("Fetching data for venue: {}".format(index + 1))
    venue = []
    url = ('https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?q={}' + 
          '&start=0&count=1&lat={}&lon={}&sort=real_distance').format(row['name'], row['lat'], row['lng'])
    try:
        result = requests.get(url, headers = headers).json()
    except:
        print("There was an error...")
    try:

        if (len(result['restaurants']) > 0):
            venue.append(result['restaurants'][0]['restaurant']['name'])
            venue.append(result['restaurants'][0]['restaurant']['location']['latitude'])
            venue.append(result['restaurants'][0]['restaurant']['location']['longitude'])
            venue.append(result['restaurants'][0]['restaurant']['average_cost_for_two'])
            venue.append(result['restaurants'][0]['restaurant']['price_range'])
            venue.append(result['restaurants'][0]['restaurant']['user_rating']['aggregate_rating'])
            venue.append(result['restaurants'][0]['restaurant']['location']['address'])
            venues_information.append(venue)
        else:
            venues_information.append(np.zeros(6))
    except:
        pass

ZomatoVenues = pd.DataFrame(venues_information, 
                                  columns = ['venue', 'latitude', 
                                             'longitude', 'price_for_two', 
                                             'price_range', 'rating', 'address'])
```

Answer (score -1):

Using [Web Scraping Language](https://github.com/whatsdis/web-scraping-language) I was able to write this:

```
GOTO https://www.zomato.com/bangalore/top-restaurants
EXTRACT {'rest_name': '//div[@class="res_title zblack bold nowrap"]', 
         'rest_address': '//div[@class="nowrap grey-text fontsize5 ttupper', 
         'cusine_type': '//div[@class="nowrap grey-text"]'} IN //div[@class="bke1zw-1 eMsYsc"]
```

This will iterate over each record element with class `bke1zw-1 eMsYsc` and pull 
each restaurant information.